# Responsive ISSUE: Trying to center the main navigation links

Tags: html, css

I was trying to center all of my main navigation links on all screens sizes. I used percentage and media queries as well but for some reason I got this hard time when it comes centering them plainly on ALL MEDIA SCREEN SIZES.

Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
<h1>TESTING</h1>
    <nav class="demo-nav">       
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Using jQuery</a>
        <a href="index2.html" >Using CSS</a>
    </nav>                
</header>




<nav class="main-nav">
<div class="container">
 <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="content">
<h2>Main Content Here!</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>


<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

</div>
```

On my CSS and media queries I have this:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) { 
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:40%;
}
}


@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:60%;

}
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) { 
.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:55%;

}

}



@media all and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
header {
    padding:5px 0 55px
}

nav.main-nav a {
    font-size:17px
}

nav.main-nav {
    height:55px
}

.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;

}

.content {
    -webkit-column-count:1;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:1;
/* Firefox */
    column-count:1
}
}




@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
header {
    padding:5px 0 55px
}

nav.main-nav a {
    font-size:17px
}

nav.main-nav {
    height:55px
}

.container {
    width:92%
}

.content {
    -webkit-column-count:1;
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:1;
/* Firefox */
    column-count:1
}
}
```

Any idea on how to improve my HTML or CSS to make it RESPONSIVE on ALL SIZES?

Here's the JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/499zLng6/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why set the navigation width to 100%, and then use text-align:center ?

Comment: That's why I am stack. Care to help?

Comment: I meant, try that. On your mobile media query, set the navigation div to full width, and to use text-align:center. That should center the nav items.

Comment: Would you mind checking the JSFIDDLE and editing it for me so that I can check where did I missed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over-complicating thing here just set the container inside the main nav to display as inline and use a text-align center on the parent element. See snippet.

```css
/***********************************************************************************************/
/* GENERAL */
/***********************************************************************************************/
body {
    font:16px/1.5 'Raleway',Arial,sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}

h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:700
}

span {
    color:#27ae60;
    font-weight:700
}

h2 {
    font-size:35px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:-20px
}

nav.demo-nav {
    width:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block
}

nav.demo-nav a {
    font-size:19px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    color:#27ae60;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:5px 15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-radius:2px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:2px solid #ecf0f1;
    border-radius:none
}

nav a.active,nav a:hover {
    background:#ecf0f1;
    color:#27ae60
}

/***********************************************************************************************/
/* HEADER AND NAV */
/***********************************************************************************************/
header {
    height:250px;
    background:#f1c40f;
    padding:23px 0
}

nav.main-nav,.content {
    position:relative
}

nav.main-nav {
    background:#fff;
    height:60px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;
    text-align: center;
}

nav.main-nav a {
    font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 19px;
    color:#27ae60
}

nav.main-nav.stickytop {
    position:fixed;
    top:0
}

.container {
    display: inline;
    /*
    margin:0 auto;
    width:31%
    */
}

/***********************************************************************************************/
/* CONTENT */
/***********************************************************************************************/
.content {
    color:#222;
    padding:50px;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count:3;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap:40;
    column-gap:40px
}

.content h2 {
    margin:0
}

/***********************************************************************************************/
/* RESPONSIVE */
/***********************************************************************************************/





@media all and (max-width: 480px) {}

/*
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) { 
.container {
margin:0 auto;
width:40%;
}
}


@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
.container {
margin:0 auto;
width:60%;

}
}

@media all and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) { 
.container {
margin:0 auto;
width:55%;

}

}

*/

@media all and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
    der {
        padding:5px 0 55px
    }
    
    nav.main-nav a {
        font-size:17px
    }
    
    nav.main-nav {
        height:55px
    }
    
    .container {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:50%;
        
    }
    
    .content {
        -webkit-column-count:1;
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count:1;
        /* Firefox */
        column-count:1
    }
}




@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {
        padding:5px 0 55px
    }
    
    nav.main-nav a {
        font-size:17px
    }
    
    nav.main-nav {
        height:55px
    }
    
    .container {
        width:92%
    }
    
    .content {
        -webkit-column-count:1;
        /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count:1;
        /* Firefox */
        column-count:1
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
    <nav class="demo-nav">       
        <a href="index.html" class="active">Using jQuery</a>
        <a href="index2.html" >Using CSS</a>
    </nav>                
</header>




<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Profile</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>


<div class="content">
    <h2>Main Content Here!</h2>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
    
</div>
```

In general it would make sense to start of with your mobile view without the use of media queries and then use media queries to adjust for bigger screen sizes.

https://jsfiddle.net/499zLng6/2/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your link's `display:inline-block;` and give your container `text-align:center;`

As you want your container to be dynamic in width and keep your links centered just give it a `width:100%` and remove any `margin's` or `padding's`.

If you want to padd it out the best way to do this would be give a padding to your link's so in this case it would be `.container li a{*CSS Here*}`.

Also remember to give your links `display:block;` as when you pad them out you want there full padded are to be hover-able and clickable.

Also its all-ways best to give your links a container like an un ordered list.

---

https://jsfiddle.net/sfLy49kh/1/

```css
header {
  padding: 5px 0 55px 0px;
}
nav.main-nav a {
  font-size: 17px
}
nav.main-nav {
  height: 55px
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.container li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.container li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="container">
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div class="content">
  <h2>Main Content Here!</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>


  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>


  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show me the JSFIDDLE LINK so that I can follow exactly? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sam just added it there

Answer (score 0):

try like below...
maybe help u...

```
nav.main-nav {
    background:#fff;
    height:60px;
    z-index:170;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dadada;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;/* added */
}

.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: auto;/* modified */
}
```

**text-aling:center;** means children will be centered.

**width: auto;** means self width is children width.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is that you create your media queries only with a `max-width` - start with the second highest resolution which you would want to have some effect, then below that media query use one with a different, lower value max-width.

I use my media queries like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) { //tablets etc.
    //responsive css for tablets
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) { //tab-phone devices.
    //responsive css for tab-phones
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) { //2012 phones.
   //css for really small devices
}
```

The CSS here will keep overwriting the styles when a breakpoint is encountered.

The reason for this is the fact that styles further down the file overwrite earlier existing ones.

This makes it so that you can first apply tablet CSS without having to take phones into account, then afterwards from the tablet layout you can then add mobile specific parts.

As for your problem with centering the menu items:
@lee in the comments is right about that.

You should just set your container to a `width: 100%` and use `text-align: center` on the links. This works alot better as you won't have to 'guess' the width of the menu all the time (which is not a good practise anyways) and the links will align themselves.

You can get rid of all of the `.container` css inside media queries and just set the CSS for `.container` as:

```
width: 100%
text-align: center`
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/499zLng6/1/)